# Function template accepting nothing less than a bidirectional iterator or a pointer

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator

I need a function template that accepts two iterators that could be pointers. If the two arguments are random_access iterators I want the return type to be an object of

`std::iterator<random_access_iterator_tag, ...>` type

else a

`std::iterator<bidirectional_iterator_tag, ...>` type.

I also want the code to refuse 
compilation if the arguments are neither a bidirectional iterator, nor a pointer. I cannot have dependency on third party libraries e.g. Boost

Could you help  me with the signature of this function so that it accepts bidirectional iterators as well as pointers, but not say input_iterator, output_iterator, forward_iterators.

One partial solution I can think of is the following

```
template<class T>
T foo( T iter1, T iter2) {
  const T tmp1 = reverse_iterator<T>(iter1);
  const T tmp2 = reverse_iterator<T>(iter2);
  // do something
}
```

The idea is that if it is not bidirectional the compiler will not let me construct a reverse_iterator from it.

Comment: This might help you: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags

Comment: @PaulManta yes it has to be based on iterator_tags, but i cannot seem to get a clean solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ meta-programming is rarely clean. Does your compiler support `enable_if`?

Comment: @PaulManta yes you are right and I am very new to templates. I have to check. I am on gcc 4.5 but the code needs to be reasonably "portable" and C++-03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a bit simpler than previous answer, no dependency on std::enable_if:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<class T>
    T do_foo(T iter1, T iter2, std::random_access_iterator_tag t)
    {
        cout << "do_foo random_access" << endl;
        return iter1;
    }
    template<class T>
    T do_foo(T iter1, T iter2, std::bidirectional_iterator_tag t)
    {
        cout << "do_foo bidirectional" << endl;
        return iter1;
    }

}
template<class T>
void foo(T iter1, T iter2)
{
    typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category t;
    detail::do_foo(iter1, iter2, t);
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    foo(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::list<int> l;
    foo(l.begin(), l.end());
    return 0;
}
```

The solution also supports other iterator_categories derived from std::random_access_iterator_tag or std::bidirectional_iterator_tag (should there be any), while std::same<> checks for strict category equality.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example with `enable_if` based on iterator tags. The substitution fails if the given T doesn't have a `iterator_category` typedef and so that overload isn't considered during overload resolution.

Since you can't use C++11, see the reference pages for [`enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [`is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) to see how you can implement it by yourself.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template<typename T>
typename
std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<
        typename T::iterator_category,
        std::bidirectional_iterator_tag
    >::value,
    T
>::type
foo(T it)
{
    std::cout << "bidirectional\n";
    return it;
}

template<typename T>
typename
std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<
        typename T::iterator_category,
        std::random_access_iterator_tag
    >::value,
    T
>::type
foo(T it)
{
    std::cout << "random access\n";
    return it;
}

// specialization for pointers

template<typename T>
T* foo(T* it)
{
    std::cout << "pointer\n";
    return it;
}

int main()
{
    std::list<int>::iterator it1;
    std::vector<int>::iterator it2;
    int* it3;
    std::istream_iterator<int> it4;
    foo(it1);
    foo(it2);
    foo(it3);
    //foo(it4); // this one doesn't compile, it4 is an input iterator
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/ffTBQR).

As per @JonathanWakely's comment, we can get rid of specialization for pointers if we use [std::iterator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits). The `typename T::iterator_category` part then becomes

```
typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category
```

Comment: Thanks. I will see if there is a quick way to roll my own enable_if.

Comment: Why not use `std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category` and get support for pointers for free?  Iterators are not required to define a nested `iterator_category`, they could specialize `iterator_traits` instead.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I didn't know iterator_traits is specialized for pointers, nice. Added that to the answer.